# Lifetime of Lua object "globally returned" to C

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

So I have a very simple Lua script like this:

```
return coroutine.create(function () coroutine.yield(1) end)
```

And then in C I run it and gets the returned value

```
lua_State* l = luaL_newstate();
if(luaL_dostring(l, script) == LUA_OK) {
  lua_State* co = lua_tothread(l, lua_gettop(l));
  lua_pop(l, 1);
}
```

Later, the C code will pass the `co` pointer back into Lua (with `lua_pushthread`) and run `coroutine.resume(co)`.

I would like to know if Lua will GC the coroutine object in the meantime, rendering the `co` pointer in C invalid? If yes, what can I do to prevent that?

Comment: You should save this value in registry to prevent GC eating it. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198472/6834680)

Answer (score 1):

With a little care, you can just leave the coroutine in the stack. Just remove the call to `lua_pop`.

Comment: but then later on I couldn't clear it from stack? Because I would have lost track of the stack position of that particular coroutine value?